# How to convert floating-point to unsigned variable?

Tags: c, byte, endianness

Could someone please help me with byte ordering regarding floating point variables? Actually the code is working correctly on Solaris, but not on Windows Xp. Here is a  piece example of my code: 
....

```
 int x_snd=1;
 float y_snd=1.13;
 struct {
      int xx_snd;
      float yy_snd;
    } data_snd;
 int x_rec;
 float y_rec;
    struct {
      int xx_rec;
      float yy_rec;
    } data_rec;  

 //marshalling 
 data_snd.xx_snd=htons(x_snd);
 data_snd.yy_snd=htonl(*(int*) &y_snd);

 //write data to socket
 send(sock1, &data_snd, ...

 //clean ...

 //read data from socket
 if recv(sock, &data_rec ...

  //unmarshalling
  x_rec=ntohs(data_rec.xx_rec);
  y_rec= *(float*) &(ntohl(data_rec.yy_rec));
```

...

Th code was compiled with gcc on Unix and with MSVC++6 on wndows.
Any of your help would be very appreciated and I would be glad if you could direct me to any link or document that gives usefull information about endianness ...

Thanking you in advance for your help,
mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot more potential variety and issues in floating point formats than just the endian problem you have to deal with when marshalling and unmarshalling integers.

One way out is to format floating point numbers as text, using `printf`, and reading them back with `strtof()` (as bmargulies indicated).

Another way that will work as long as the machines share the same `FLT_RADIX` value, is to break them into a mantissa and exponent value:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

float x = 1.13;
int x_exp;
long x_mant;

x_exp = ilogbf(x);
x_mant = (scalbnf(fabsf(x), -x_exp) - 1) * LONG_MAX;
if (x < 0.0)
    x_mant = -x_mant;
```

You then have an `int` and a `long` (`x_exp` and `x_mant` from the above code) to put onto the wire, which you can use the normal `ntohl()` and `htonl()` functions to do.  To convert these back into a `float`, use:

```
x = scalbnf((fabsf(x_mant) / LONG_MAX) + 1, x_exp);
if (x_mant < 0)
    x = -x;
```

Note that most machines have a `FLT_RADIX` value (defined in `float.h`) of 2, so if you check for that during compilation and abort if it's something else, you should be reasonably portable.

Comment: thank for your help

Could you please give me more information about the second was you described ? Any link that descibes this way of FLT_RADIX value would be very appreciated!

thanks again,
mk

Comment: Well, I've provided you with the code (which I just wrote myself, so I don't have any links to point you to).  If you do some research on the Sign-Mantissa-Exponent way of representing floating point numbers, it should become clear what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Please correct me then, if this is right !

int x_snd=1; 
float y_snd=1.13; 
//
int y_snd_exp;
long y_snd_mant;

struct {      
 int xx_snd;      
 float yy_snd;    
 } data_snd; 
 
//marshalling 
 
y_snd_exp = ilogbf(y_snd);
y_snd_mant = (scalbnf(fabsf(y_snd), -y_snd_exp) - 1) * LONG_MAX;
if (y_snd < 0.0)  y_snd_mant = -y_snd_mant;

data_snd.xx_snd=htons(x_snd); 
data_snd.yy_snd=htonl(y_snd_mant); 

//write data to socket 
send(sock1, &data_snd, ... 

...

Comment: int x_rec; 
 float y_rec;  
 //
 int y_rec_exp;
 long y_rec_mant;

 struct {      
  int xx_rec;      
  float yy_rec;    
  } data_rec;   

//read data from socket 
if recv(sock1, &data_rec ... 

//unmarshalling  
x_rec=ntohs(data_rec.xx_rec);  
y_rec_mant=ntohl(data_rec.yy_rec);

x = scalbnf((fabsf(y_rec_mant) / LONG_MAX) + 1, y_rec_exp);
if (y_rec_mant < 0)    y_rec = -y_rec;
...

Regards and thanks again for all your help,
mk

Comment: No.  The `y_snd_exp` and `y_snd_mant` values should both be sent over the wire (after passing through `htonl()`).  You also can't just write the `struct` in one pass like that - structs can have padding.  You should write each of the values seperately.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for disturbing you with it

just for some clarification  ..

you said that I can't use struct because it can cause padding. But, it is hard to write each of the variables seperately. Is this possible to exchange data in the form of array?

Regards and thanks again for all of your help,
mk

Comment: Yes, you can use `memcpy()` to copy the underlying representation of each variable into an array of `char` and send that.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to exchange data with FLT_RADIX value and I would like to let you know that I succeded to compile it only on Salaris. But on windows, I get errors regarding 'ilogbf' and 'scalbnf' declaration. I use MSVC++6 for compiling on windows. Is there any library of IEEE functions that should be included? On solaris, I get this warming of converting to `long int' from `float' regarding this line: x_mant = (scalbnf(fabsf(x_snd), -x_exp) - 1) * LONG_MAX;
Thanks for all your help, mk

Comment: The conversion from `long` to `float` is expected - you can add a cast (`fabsf((float)x_snd)`) to eliminate the warning.  Those functions are C99, I'm not sure if/when they've been added to Microsoft's implementation.  You can rework it to use the `frexp` and `ldexp` functions instead, which are C89 standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generally bad idea. The format of floating point numbers isn't necessarily the same on different hardware, even after accounting for byte order. I would have to recommend shipping them here and there as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both systems have the same floating point format, `yy_rec` is a `float`; `ntohl` takes an `unsigned long`; the floating point value, potentially with incorrect endianness, is being converted to an integer representation when it is passed into `ntohl`.

You should be getting a compiler warning due to the conversion from `float` to `unsigned long`.

Comment: This is crucial. The code as written ( y_rec= *(float*) &(ntohl(data_rec.yy_rec));
) shouldn't ever work, as it will convert yy_rec (a float) to an unsigned long and then flip its bytes.